# Xunit.net and Moq Assert that method is called regardless of an exception being thrown

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit.net

In a method I'm testing I want to assert that a call has been made before an exception is thrown.

Currently the Act/Assert section of the test looks like this:

```
Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => sut.HandleMessage(messageToProcess));

mock.Verify(n => n.Method(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
```

but that breaks the rule of only asserting once since I'm asserting that `HandleMessage` throws an exception (which has its own test case) and then verifying `mock.Method` was called.
This means that the test fails if an exception hasn't been thrown which isn't what I'm testing for here.

How would I verify the method has been called even if an exception hasn't been thrown, would a try-catch-finally be acceptable here (as below)?

```
try
{
    sut.HandleMessage(messageToProcess);
}
catch{}
finally
{
    mock.Verify(n => n.Method(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
}
```

Comment: I would say a single assert is best practice but not an unbreakable rule. if you are testing control flow within a method then it seems reasonable that you are testing one logical concept so personally, I would just go with your original example

Comment: If I understand your goal, you want to asset that a method was called during message handling (even in case of exceptions), thus your **2nd** example is the one that exactly describes that scenario.